# References numbering in parenthesis using thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

I am using the thebibliography environment for my references. Once I cite a particular reference (\cite{ref1}) in my text it appears like [1] for instance. I want to make it in parenthesis (1) instead. Is that possible?

With Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you wish to use round parentheses instead of square brackets both in the citation call-outs and in the bibliography itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Change appearance of numeric labels in citation call-outs
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}

% Change appearance of numeric labels in bibliography 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{myref}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{myref} Some entry.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. I wanted to ask one more thing though. Shall I use the unsrt in thebibliography? Because my references are not sorted in ascending order as presented in the text. They sorted as  imported in the references.

Comment: @user161260 -  The choice of sorting method -- alphabetic by authors' names, or "unsorted', i.e., by order of first citation call-out -- is entirely up to you. I don't know what field you're in; there may be a convention to use one or the other sorting method. What I would really like to recommend is that you learn how to use BibTeX (or biblatex). Once the bib file is set up, switching from one bibliography style to another is trivially easy.

Comment: @user161260 You can't use that in `thebibliography`, can you? The items are typeset in whatever order you specify them. If you don't want to worry about sorting them yourself or you want to be able to easily change the sort order, you need to use BibTeX or Biblatex/Biber as far as I know? But I don't know much about `thebibliography` environment?